Sketchy use of multivariable chain rule under too weak hypoteses
I've found this statement in my real analysis course notes:

Let $f: B_r (x_0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ ($B_r (x_0) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m : d(x, x_0) < r \}$) be a function such that its partial derivatives exist on all of $B_r(x_0)$ and these partial derivatives are also such that their partial derivatives exist in $B_r(x_0)$ ( we are not assuming $f$ to be differentiable ).
Then, for any $x \in B_r(x_0)$, the function
$$
F: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}\ \mbox{given by}\ F(t) = f(x_0 + t (x - x_0))
$$
is twice differentiable and we have

$F' (t) = \left< \nabla f(x_0 + t (x- x_0)), x - x_0 \right>$
and $\quad F''(t) = \left< H_{f} (x_0 + t (x-x_0))(x - x_0), x-x_0 \right>,\quad$ where $H_f$ is the hessian matrix of the function $f$ ( which in our hypoteses, is not necessarily symmetric ).


To prove this statement, the lecture notes directly use the chain rule for multivariable functions, which seems very sketchy here because the hypoteses are too weak (if we suppose the second derivatives of $f$ to be continuous or its first derivatives to be differentiable then this is really easy).
I'm looking for a counterexample/proof.


A good starting point is whether the first assertion (the formula for $F'(t)$) must even hold. For example, can you create a function that has partial derivatives but is not differentiable along the line $y=x$ in $\Bbb R^2$ for which it fails?
